# Commutativity on n terms implies associativity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was thinking about commutativity on $n$ terms for some left-associative, binary operation $\star$, when I noticed that commutativity on $n$ terms seemed to imply associativity, by rearranging the terms to get the desired associations. Further commutativity on 2 terms and associativity implies commutativity on $n$ terms according to this sketch of an inductive proof:

1. Rearrange $a_1, \dots, a_{n-1}$ to be in their desired relative order (uses inductive hypothesis).
2. Swap $a_n$ with the elements we want after it to get the desired order (uses associativity and inductive hypothesis).

So one could say:

$$\text{Commutativity on } n \text{ terms } \Leftrightarrow \text{Commutativity on 2 terms and associativity}$$

This fact seems odd to me since I always thought of commutativity and associativity as separate concepts. Is my conclusion correct? Is this conclusion useful in any meaningful way? Namely, are there any conceptual advantages to defining some structures as commutative on $n$ terms?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "commutativity on $n$ terms." The obvious way to define this requires associativity. Note also that "left-associative" is not a property of an operation, it's a convention that says you only want to look at certain parenthesizations.

Comment: I would rather say "there is no obvious way to define this without associativity"

Comment: I would define commutativity on n terms as "for any permutation of $n$ terms $\sigma$, $a_1 \star ... \star a_n = a_{\sigma(1)} \star ... \star a_{\sigma(n)}$. By convention we let $a_1 \star ... \star a_n = (...(a_1 \star a_2) ... \star a_n)$. I see how if $\star$ satisfies this property, then it's associative, but how did I use associativity to define it?